# Git overwrote newer changes in favor of old ones (including deleting files)

Tags: git

We have a common develop branch which contains all QA tested features. We had one coworker finish their features and QA merged it into develop.

This not only deleted a large number of files but also when I tried to merge develop back into my branch (to resolve any conflicts) it would overwrite my changes (newer) in favor of develop (older).

What could cause this to happen? Seems like it was an isolated incident but we want to make sure it doesn't happen again. It's almost as if the "modified" time on the file was newer on develop, which is impossible.

Comment: Well, I would check the most obvious reason first: the developer who did that merge did so by taking the source branch, thus removing changes done in the target branch.

Comment: Git should never just "overwrite" changes. It would report a conflict instead. Please provide a linewise example of what actually has happened.

Answer (score 0):

First things first: "modified times" have nothing to do with how merge results are calculated.  In fact, git does not give preference to newer changes, or to older ones, or anything of the sort.  A change is a change.

During a merge, git finds a "merge base" (the most recent commit that's an ancestor of both (or all) commits involved in the merge), figures out all the changes made since the merge base (on both (all) branches), and figures out what would happen if you applied *all* of those changes to the merge base.  The only time it's necessary to "prefer" one change vs. the other is if both branches modified the same hunk of code, and in that case the default behavior is to report a merge conflict.

And yet you observed old versions of code overwriting new versions of code, so why?

I think the most likely reason is not accounting for a usage of `git revert` somewhere along the line.  This is not to say that `revert` were bad; often it's the best thing to use.  But in some cases, it has consequences that can be confusing if you're not aware of them.

In particular if anyone has reverted a merge commit, it tends to lead to this kind of thing; or branching and then reverting commits from before the branch point.

Of course that's speculation (and if I tried to recommend a fix without knowing more, that would be dangerous speculation). It could be something different.  To know, one would have to analyze your history.  If you're merging `feature` with `develop`, you could start by saying

```
git merge-base feature develop
```

which will tell you the ID of the commit used for a merge base.  Then you could use `git diff <id> feature` and `git diff <id> develop` to see what git sees during the merge.  Or trace the evolution of changes with `git log -p <id>..feature`, etc.

But then again, maybe asking around reveals that `revert` was used in a way that, on closer inspection, explains what happened; in which case, instead of digging through the history you could instead just make sure everyone understands the nuances of working with that command.